# socket.gethostbyaddr() on a linux system and local network

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, centos

I have a django application using this function, i'm trying to get the computer name of the ip address accessing my application. I'm doing this by using [django-ipware](https://github.com/un33k/django-ipware) to get the client's ip address, this part is working fine. Then i'm using [`socket.gethostbyaddr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyaddr) to get the client's computer name, this works fine on my windows development machine.

```
def get_comp_name(request):
    client_ip = get_client_ip(request)
    try:
        comp_name = socket.gethostbyaddr(client_ip[0])[0]
    except socket.herror:
        comp_name = ''
```

When i tried to deploy to a centOS 7 machine, I get the following error when executing `socket.gethostbyaddr()` on local network ip addresses.

> socket.herror: [Errno 1] Unknown host

I can ping local ip addresses without issue. Am I missing a configuration on my centOS 7 machine?

Comment: Same problems on me, still looking for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS server needs to have an entry for this to work. Check /etc/resolv.conf if the DNS server IP is correct, check if DNS server is reachable from the CentOS node and finally, check if the entry in the DNS server is correct.

Comment: This answer would be better as a comment.